Poetry install failing with SSLError: Max retries exceeded on GitHub HTTPSConnectionPool
I am encountering an error when running the poetry install command in my Python project. The error message is as follows:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: ... (Caused by SSLError(FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')))

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps, but none have resolved the issue:

Verified my internet connection.
Checked that I have the latest version of Poetry installed.
Ensured my Git and OpenSSL installations are up-to-date.
Confirmed that the repository URL is correct and accessible from a browser.

Despite all this, the error persists. It seems related to SSL or Git configuration, but I am unsure how to resolve it.
Environment Details:
OS: 14.7.1 (23H222)
Python version: 3.11.9]
Poetry version: 1.8.5
Git version: 2.45.2

Has anyone encountered this issue before or can provide guidance on how to resolve it?

What's the command itself? THe 5th point probably does not apply since the install is from github not pypi index.

True I have a row for installing a package from github using https from a certain revision

Here’s how I resolved the issue:
1. Install or Update certifi in the Virtual Environment
Make sure the certifi package is installed and up-to-date:
pip install --upgrade certifi

Locate the cacert.pem File
Use the following command to find where the cacert.pem file is located:
python -m certifi

2. Copy the cacert.pem File to the Expected Location
From the error message (I tried to clone the repo from github using https), I saw that the virtual environment was looking for the cacert.pem file here:
/Users/user/.../certifi/cacert.pem
If the file is missing, copy it from another working virtual environment. For example:
mkdir -p /Users/user/.../certifi/
cp /path/to/working/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem /Users/user/.../cacert.pem

3. Retry the Command
After copying the cacert.pem file to the correct location, I retried the poetry install command and it worked!.

I had the same problem because I worked behind company vpn.
This worked for windows.
This is not recommended solution but if you are left with no choice this worked for me:
Change version to Poetry 1.6.1
pip uninstall poetry
pip install poetry=1.5.1

upon completion, use the following commands:
poetry source add fpho https://files.pythonhosted.org
poetry config certificates.fpho.cert false
poetry source add pypi
poetry config certificates.PyPI.cert false
poetry config certiticates.pypi.cert false

I don't really like this solution and I cant manage to add my own signed .crt file so I used this.
